# Cannot read manifest file error with chrome extension

Tags: javascript, python, json, selenium, web-scraping

I have here a snippet of my code,

```
options = Options()
    options.add_extension("/Users/.../Desktop/proxy.zip")
    options.headless = False
    options.add_argument("--incognito")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/.../Downloads/chromedriver', options=options)
    driver.get(url)
```

Whenever I run this, I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/.../Documents/code.py", line 95, in <module>
    M_A()
  File "/Users/.../Documents/code.py", line 32, in M_A
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/.../Downloads/chromedriver', options=options)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 76, in __init__
    RemoteWebDriver.__init__(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: cannot process extension #1
from unknown error: cannot read manifest
```

And I have no idea why. I looked at the other solutions on this site and elsewhere but they didn't help me out. I don't really know why my manifest.json file can't be read.

Comment: always put full error messag (starting at word "Traceback") in question(not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: @furas thank you for the suggestion, I added the whole error message